# Writing triggers for mcelog

Tags: linux, rhel, monitoring, hardware, mcelog

Just starting to look into `mcelog` for the first time (I've enabled it and seen syslog output before, but this is the first time I'm trying to do something non-default). I'm looking for information on how to write triggers for it. Specifically, I'm looking for what kinds of events `mcelog` can react to, how it decides which scripts to execute, and so on. Best I can make from the example trigger is that it sets a bunch of environmental variables before invoking the script. So does it just try to execute everything in the trigger directory (which is `/etc/mcelog` on RHEL) and let the script decide what it wants to act on?

I've seen other trigger scripts with names that look like MCE events, is that convention or does that have a special function? I created a trigger called `/etc/mcelog/joel.sh` which just sends a basic email to my gmail account. A few days ago apparently the trigger went off because I got an email from the script without manually running the script. I didn't think to pipe `env` output to the `mailx` command in `joel.sh` so I don't know what hardware event triggered the script execution or why `mcelog` picked `joel.sh` as the script to execute for it.

Basically, I'm looking for an answer that will give me a basic orientation with `mcelog`, it's triggering system, and how I can use it to monitor my hardware health. I'm pretty sure I can figure out the more advanced stuff once I get my bearings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the sample `mcelog.conf` config file it looks to contain most if not all of the types of triggers it can deal with.

#### DIMMs

```
[dimm]
#
# execute these triggers when the rate of corrected or uncorrected
# errors per DIMM exceeds the threshold
# Note when the hardware does not report DIMMs this might also
# be per channel
# The default of 10/24h is reasonable for server quality·
# DDR3 DIMMs as of 2009/10
#uc-error-trigger = dimm-error-trigger
uc-error-threshold = 1 / 24h
#ce-error-trigger = dimm-error-trigger
ce-error-threshold = 10 / 24h
```

#### Sockets

```
[socket]
# Threshold and trigger for uncorrected memory errors on a socket
# mem-uc-error-trigger = socket-memory-error-trigger
mem-uc-error-threshold = 100 / 24h
# Threshold and trigger for corrected memory errors on a socket
mem-ce-error-trigger = socket-memory-error-trigger
mem-ce-error-threshold = 100 / 24h
```

#### Cache

```
[cache]
# Processing of cache error thresholds reported by Intel CPUs
cache-threshold-trigger = cache-error-trigger
```

#### Page

```
[page]
# Memory error accouting per 4K memory page
# Threshold for the correct memory errors trigger script
memory-ce-threshold = 10 / 24h
# Trigger script for corrected errors
# memory-ce-trigger = page-error-trigger
```

#### Triggers

Triggers can be controlled in this section.

```
[trigger]
# Maximum number of running triggers
children-max = 2
# execute triggers in this directory
directory = /etc/mcelog
```

#### Sample triggers

There are [some sample triggers](https://github.com/andikleen/mcelog/tree/master/triggers) here on the mcelog github page.

#### Sample trigger script, `dimm-error-triggers`:

```
#!/bin/sh
#  This shell script can be executed by mcelog in daemon mode when a DIMM
#  exceeds a pre-configured error threshold
# 
# environment:
# THRESHOLD     human readable threshold status
# MESSAGE   Human readable consolidated error message
# TOTALCOUNT    total count of errors for current DIMM of CE/UC depending on
#       what triggered the event
# LOCATION  Consolidated location as a single string
# DMI_LOCATION  DIMM location from DMI/SMBIOS if available
# DMI_NAME  DIMM identifier from DMI/SMBIOS if available
# DIMM      DIMM number reported by hardware
# CHANNEL   Channel number reported by hardware
# SOCKETID  Socket ID of CPU that includes the memory controller with the DIMM
# CECOUNT   Total corrected error count for DIMM
# UCCOUNT   Total uncorrected error count for DIMM
# LASTEVENT Time stamp of event that triggered threshold (in time_t format, seconds)
# THRESHOLD_COUNT Total umber of events in current threshold time period of specific type
#
# note: will run as mcelog configured user
# this can be changed in mcelog.conf

logger -s -p daemon.err -t mcelog "$MESSAGE"
logger -s -p daemon.err -t mcelog "Location: $LOCATION"

[ -x ./dimm-error-trigger.local ] && . ./dimm-error-trigger.local

exit 0
```

#### References

- [mcelog / mcelog.conf](https://github.com/andikleen/mcelog/blob/master/mcelog.conf)
- [mcelog - memory error handling in user space at Linux Kongress 2010 - paper](http://www.halobates.de/lk10-mcelog.pdf)
- [mcelog - memory error handling in user space at Linux Kongress 2010 - slides](http://www.halobates.de/mcelog-lk10-pres.pdf)
- [Andi's recent papers and presentations](http://www.halobates.de/)
- [andikleen/mcelog - github page](https://github.com/andikleen/mcelog)

Comment: Thanks, even though the answer is basically common sense I guess it somehow eluded me when I was reading the configuration file. Always good to get someone else to look at the problem for issues like that.

Comment: Any ideas on why my `joel.sh` script just suddenly fired off in the middle of no where?

Comment: No this is good info to have on U&L so I was glad you asked it. I never heard of `mcelog` so it was worth it! I was looking into that `joel.sh` issue b/c it was bugging me too. I couldn't put my finger on it either. I saw a mention somewhere that there is a default trigger scenario, lost where I saw it. Was there other scripts in that dir. or just `joel.sh`?

Comment: `joel.sh` is the only executable file in that directory, the only other file is the `mcelog.conf` file.

Comment: That's probably why it was run then. I saw it in one of the links I referenced above, if I get a chance I'll dig it up but it seemed to be saying that if there was only a single script in that directory it was going to run it by default. Seemed a little aggressive to me but it kind of makes sense.